# PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: php, html, database, laravel, pdo

I've got this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
>   nodename nor servname provided, or not known

and

> PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
>   nodename nor servname provided, or not known.

When I try to run php artisan serve in terminal I got always same error. did anyone already solved this Problem ?

I use Xampp on Mac.

This's my database.php.

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhostphp artisan make:migration create_users_table'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

and this one is my env.

```php
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=-----
DB_USERNAME=------
DB_PASSWORD=------
```

I got this two error. since 2 week I try to solve a problem. but I could't find solution. I've already done all solution on stackoverflow.

Thaks For Your Help.

Link : https://imgyukle.com/i/oEJWhR

Comment: Is `127.0.0.1  localhost` set in your `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: it's localhost.

Comment: I understand you're using localhost.  I was asking if the line `127.0.0.1 localhost` exists in your `/etc/hosts` file to bind that IP to localhost.  It should exist and be uncommented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's because of the host's line! It should be

```
'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
```

OR

```
'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
```

This part of the line `php artisan make:migration create_users_table` is a Laravel command! You're supposed to do it in the command line (the terminal)!

Comment: @SadıkMenduhAğar When you put the informations directly in your database.php, is it working?